# Have different section titles in \tableofcontents and \localtableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

**Question**

Is it possible to define shorter section titles for etoc's localtableofcontents without affecting the main toc and the section titles themselves? Perhaps something akin to \section[short-title]{in-text-title} but only the localtoc prints out *short-title*.

**Background**

I am using the \localtableofcontents of etoc to produce a small toc for each chapter.
I want this local toc to a shorter version of the section titles without affecting the section title in the main toc. I also want to define this title manually and not have it automatically abbreviated.

**A conceptual example**

```
Main toc
    1 Chapter title
        1.1 A very long section title


1 Chapter title

Local toc
   1.1 A short section title

1.1 A very long section title
...
```